# Django form and User data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)       

class Contract(models.Model):                   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()   
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

How can i configure a django form so that only clients associated with that user show in the field in the form?
My initial thought was this in my forms.py:

```
    client = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Client.objects.filter(user__username = User.username))
```

But it didn't work. So how else would I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating a dynamic choice field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field)

Comment: I'm now getting a UnboundLocalError, local variable 'contractForm' referenced before assignment on this line in my view: 
contractForm = contractForm(request.user)

Comment: Isn't the form class `ContractForm`, with a capital C? It should probably read `contractForm = ContractForm(request.user)`.

Comment: That got it now on to another error. It's saying that __init__() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code. Can you edit your question to show us what you have so far?

Comment: Fixed that error. Now on to why the for isn't rendering. The last error was because I was using forms.ChoiceField instead of forms.ModelChoiceField