# Is there a way to override form values in template?

Tags: django

I have the following in my `forms.py` to define choices on a form input:

```
selection = forms.TypedChoiceField (label="Format", choices = (("Choice1", "Choice1"), ("Choice2", "Choice2"), ("Choice3", "Choice3"),widget = forms.RadioSelect, required= True)
```

And in my template, I currently have the following line of code which allows people to select one of these choices.

```
{{ formtoaddselection.selection }}
```

This is fine in general, but I have a corner case where I want to sometimes overwrite those default choices to say `CornerCase1` and `CornerCase2`.

Is it possible to override those defaults in the template, and if so, how?

Comment: you could use some javascript?

Comment: Why override the values in your template? Use dynamic choices and put the logic in your form class where it belongs: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3419997/630877

Comment: Thanks @arie;.. the problem with that method (I think) is that I don't have the variable I need by the time the view/form is loaded... It's after a user clicks on a particular item that I know the choices I need to populate...

Answer (score 2):

The only way to have non trivial behavior in the template layer is to build [template tags.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

Something like:

```
@register.simple_tag
def override_form_choices(field, *args, **kwargs):
    field.choices = [(x, x) for x in args]
    return field


{% override_form_choices formtoaddselection.selection 'foo' 'bar' 'baz' %}
```

You may find an assignment tag is more appropriate here / readable / flexible here.