# How to add non model field to ModelForm in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm hoping this makes sense, here is what I want to do *(for whatever reason)*.

I would like to create a **non-model form field** within my **model form**?

For example, below I have a model form, I would like at **init** to add an **extra field**  that's **not contained within the model** called **template**. I **don't save** this new field so it does not need to be in my model or to I want it to be (I do some fancy ajax stuff with it.).

**forms.py**

```
class testForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(testForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            this_templates = Template.objects.for_user(user)

         self.fields["templates"] = forms.??????????
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
self.fields["templates"] = forms.CharField()
```

Or if you prefer another field type check [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#built-in-field-classes) for possible options.

And for additional background information take a look at [Overloading Django Form Fields](http://pydanny.com/overloading-form-fields.html).

Comment: Ok cool somehting like this then....  self.fields["templates"] = forms.ChoiceField(queryset=this_templates) however this gives an error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Comment: A ```ChoiceField``` is not a ```ModelChoiceField```. It doesn't take a ```queryset``` but a ```choices``` argument. Check this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420588/630877