# How to remove redundant choices from django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am writing a django app to manage the static content on my page so that the end user can update content throughout without having to change the code server side. Part of this means keeping track of which sections have customized definitions. Thus, these sections are one of my models for the app. The issue is that I want to limit the choices about which sections can be customized.

Here is what a section will be like then:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
CHOICES = (
    ("Media_Music_Description","Media Page - Music Description"),
    ("Media_Photos_Description","Media Page - Photos Description"),
    ("Media_Videos_Description","Media Page - Videos Description"),
    ("Home_Content", "Home Page - Content"),
    ("About_Content", "About Page - Content")
)

class StaticItem(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, unique=True, max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category


class ContentBlock(models.Model):
    rank = models.SmallIntegerField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('StaticItem')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1024)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %d" % (self.parent.location, self.rank)
```

In the end I will move the `CHOICES` definition to my settings file. But, for now the issue is that even though the `StaticItem` model has a unique field determined by those choices, all of the choices appear in the admin panel drop down when creating a new `StaticItem`. While they appear as choices, django prevents the user from creating a `StaticItem` whose location is already used by another. My question then is how to only display the options from `CHOICES` which have not been used by a `StaticItem` yet. Basically, there must be a 1 to 1 relationship between the two, but I'm running into issues because I don't want to make CHOICES a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real way to do this is to provide a custom model form for the admin panel and override its behavior in there. I was hoping for an easier solution (like being able to pass a function into choices), but that cannot be an option because of how choices is used when defining the database. Therefore, since you can't have some function generating options for the columns of your database, you instead control which options are actually displayed in the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a class method in StaticItem that did something like:

```
def choices_available(self):
    # query the choices that have been used in StaticItem into "used"
    return [c for c in choices if c is not in used]
```

And then use the result of StaticItem.choices_available() to populate your admin page field.

As a side note: it is conventional and cleaner to put the CHOICES definition within class StaticItem instead of at module scope as you have it.

Comment: My issue isn't really getting the unused choices, but rather how to make those appear as the options when creating a new `StaticItem` in the admin interface. I was hoping there might be something more elegant than overriding the admin model.

Comment: Adding a model method doesn't "override the admin model" (whatever that might mean). Model methods are *the* way that you give dynamic behavior to static data. When you have a model method it behaves like a ModelField for most uses like making an admin page.

Comment: I'm talking about overriding the admin form model. Simply having a helper method attached to my model doesn't help anything appear on the admin panel. You can't call a class method within the models type definitions since it hasn't been instantiated yet. I think that choices as far as part of the Model are set at initialization, which means if I want dynamic behavior on admin panel I have to change the way it's displayed not the way it's stored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override admin form with dynamic choices for StaticItem. See this question: [Creating a dynamic choice field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field)

Comment: I've got that much working, however after searching to see what choices are not use and populating the drop down, it is counting it's original value as used and so its current value does not appear in the dropdown. In other words it only effects it when editing an entry, it doesn't show it's current value as an option. How can I get the instance that I'm editing from a ModelForm?