# ManyToManyField limit choices to dynamic foreign model

Tags: django, dynamic, manytomanyfield, limit-choices-to

```
class TrialRun(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(NewProduct, verbose_name='Product',)

class Component(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(NewProduct, verbose_name='Product',)

class TrialIssue(models.Model):
    trialrun = models.ForeignKey(TrialRun, verbose_name='Trial Run',)
    components = models.ManyToManyField(
        Component,limit_choices_to{product=trialrun.product})
```

How could I realize the thinking of `(Component, limit_choices_to={product=trialrun.product})`?

i can not use the following

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TrialIssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # make sure we're editing a saved model
    if self.instance.id:
        self.fields['components'].queryset = Component.objects.filter(product=self.instance.trialrun.product)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define it on the database level, so you need to do this inside a form. There is an example on [Creating a dynamic choice field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field) for a ForeignKey field, but it should be able to change it to work with ManyToManyFields as well.

If you also want it checked inside the model, you have to add your own custom validator as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: hi, i use the one in my question, but no effect

Comment: hi, i can not find a way for the manytomanyfield, couldyou help more clearly?

Comment: it is also very like the unresoved question at stackoverflow.com/questions/19726274/django-models-limit-manytomanyfield-to-owner