# How do I base my Django form ChoiceField on the current user?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django form in which the current user must select his or her favorite dog, so something like:

```
class DogForm(forms.Form):
  favorite_dog = forms.ChoiceField(label='Select favorite dog.', choices=[])
```

Unfortunately, the user currently logged in is recorded in the session, which the Django form lacks access to, so I am unable to populate the choices list. The choices should be of the form

```
[(dog.pk, dog.name) for dog in user.dogs.all()]
```

Can I somehow feed the choices in through the form constructor? As in, when I construct the form for validation, I tried altering the constructor like

```
my_form = DogForm(request.POST, user=current_logged_in_user)
```

Comment: You mean like so http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420588/630877 ?

Comment: I don't think that works for me. When I instantiate a form with `form = DogForm(request.POST, user=current_logged_in_user)`, I get an error: `__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'`