# selective display of model choices in django

Tags: django, forms, model

In my django application I have a model field called 'status'. In one of the forms to get data for this field, I only want to display a subset of all choices available in the model. Is there a way to remove a choice from a form? I need the removed choice in the database and the admin interface where I can select it.

```
status = models.CharField(STATUS_FIELD_NAME, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                          default=STATUS_DEFAULT,
                          max_length=3)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a dynamic choice field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field)

Comment: it is a duplicate, look at @Anentropic link; you need to setup a ModelForm to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the subset of choices in your form:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    SUBSET_CHOICES = (
        (YourModel.CHOICE_ONE, _('First choice')),
        (YourModel.CHOICE_TWO, _('Second choice')),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['choice', ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'].choices = self.SUBSET_CHOICES
```