# Python/Django form where user selects from a list of Images

Tags: python, django, django-userena

I'm new to django and want to make a form that allows a user to select one of three images using radio boxes, once the user selects the image it is saved to their profile and displayed on their profile page.

I am using:
django 1.8.3
userena 1.4.1

Any help or links to documentation that will help would be great.

Comment: Try to use django form to represent your choices. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/

Comment: Yea that's what I have been doing I can make the form and every thing but I  get stuck at making the submit save the selected image to the users profile.

Comment: post you forms.py and views.py code. Where do you stuck ?

Comment: Here's a complete example. https://coderwall.com/p/bz0sng/simple-django-image-upload-to-model-imagefield. But you should do some of your own research and be more specific about your problem.

Comment: I have done my own research and I understand how to allow a user to upload an image, what I want is the user to have to select from a set of images that I provide.

Answer (score 2):

Basic example. Models:

```
def get_upload(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/user_%s_%s_%s" % (instance.user, datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S"), filename)

class UserModel():
    # your fields
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload, default='')
```

[FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField)

Forms:

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Auxiliary class to make file uploading more convenient."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('image')
```

View:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        profile = request.user.profile
        image_type = request.POST.get("image_type", None)
        if image_type == "blah":
            profile.image = request.FILES[image_type]
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Error")
        request.user.profile.save()
        return HttpResponse('OK')
```

[request.FILES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES)

JS with soem Jquery:

```
var SIZE_RESTRICT = 10*1024*1024;       //10 Mbytes

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".upload_file").find(".upload_button").click(send_file);
    $(".upload_file").find(".upload_file_form").find("input[type='file']").click(enable_upload);
});

function send_file()
{
    if ($(this).attr("enabled") != "true") return;
    // Prevent double-triple clicks with multiple upload.
    $(this).attr("enabled", "false");
    var form = $(this).parent().find(".upload_file_form").get(0);
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var file = $(form).find("input[type='file']").get(0).files[0];
    // Not sure about this
    // Prevent attack with HUGE files, that will smash server memory
    // TODO: Restrict file types (Ex. MIME-image, pdf, doc)
    if (file.size > SIZE_RESTRICT)
    {
        alert("File is too big.");
        return;
    }
    formData.append("proof_type", $(this).attr("upload-type"));
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var that = this;
    // TODO: Define another events like error, abort
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        // TODO: Progressbar as e.loaded / e.total
        if (e.lengthComputable)
            console.log((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
        else
            console.log("Cant count length");
      };

    xhr.onload = function(e){
          // TODO: Show success confirmation to user.
        if (this.response == "Success")
        {
            // pass
            alert(this.response);
        }
        else if (this.response == "Error")
        {
            // pass
            alert(this.response);
        }
        else
        {
            // pass
        }
      };

    xhr.open('POST', '/upload_proof');
    xhr.send(formData);
}

function enable_upload()
{
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".upload_button").attr("enabled", "true");
}
```

Actually another simple example could be founded in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Answer (score 1):

If the set of images is small and fixed, the best option is to use the [`choice` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices) in the field that defines the image within your model.

The image field could be the path to the image file on the file system.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    GOOD = 'Good.jpg'
    UGLY = 'Ugly.jpg'
    BAD = 'Bad.jpg'
    AVATAR_CHOICES = (
        (GOOD, 'Good'),
        (UGLY, 'Ugly'),
        (BAD, 'Bad'),
    )
    avatar_img = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                  choices=AVATAR_CHOICES,
                                  default=GOOD)
```

Another option is to use [`FilePathField` as your model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield)

```
FilePathField(path="/path/to/avatar_images", match="*.jpg", recursive=False)
```

Another way is to fill the form field dynamically when the form is instantiated.
Please see this [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field) for more on that.

However, as Django docs say

> But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re
>   probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey

To specify Radiobuttons to be used for the form field, please refer to the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#specifying-widgets) on how to set the proper widget.