# How to edit select option values in Django forms?

Tags: python, django

I want to edit select option values in my django form. 
Right now the value for option in select is the related variant_id.

models.py

```
class ReceiptDetail(models.Model):
    variant = models.ForeignKey('ProductVariant')
```

forms.py

```
class ReceiptDetailForm(forms.ModelForm)    
    class Meta:
        model = ReceiptDetail
        fields = ['product_id', 'variant', 'size', 'quantity', 'price']
```

the resulting html from select on 'variant':

```
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="98">Charm I (Charm I)</option>
<option value="97">Small potion V (Small potion V)</option>
<option value="90">Big potion V (Big potion V)</option>
<option value="100">Charm III (Charm III)</option>
<option value="93">Small potion I (Small potion I)</option>
<option value="94">Small potion II (Small potion II)</option>
<option value="81">Colorfully (Colorfully)</option>
```

Note that the value for each option is the VARIANT id. I want to change that value to PRODUCT id (that's related to the variant).

I'm guessing widgets are the answer, but I don't know how to access the option attributes inside the select object. Here's what I've tried:

widgets.py:

```
class VariantIDWidget(forms.widgets.Select):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VariantIDWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        out = super(VariantIDWidget, self).render(name, value,
            attrs={'value': 'test'})
        return out
```

This will change the value of <\select>, not its related <\options>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should exclude the `variant` in the `fields` defined in your form, and do something in the form `__init__` method:

```
class ReceiptDetailForm(forms.ModelForm)    
    class Meta:
        model = ReceiptDetail
        fields = ['product_id', 'size', 'quantity', 'price']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReceiptDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # this is pseudo code but you should get all variants
        # then get the product related to each variant
        variants = Variant.objects.all()
        products = [(i.product.id, i.product.name) for i in variants]
        self.fields['product'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=products)
```

It's a common technique, see some other SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field).

Comment: You can also just do: `self.fields['product'].choices = products`