# How to give choice to froms.ChoiceField for Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class CountryLevelOptimization(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    country = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=(('A','a'),('B','b')))
```

Above is my Django form in which country is a ChoiceField
Following is my python code.

```
def Homepage(request):
    choices = (('Country1','India'),('Country2','USA'))
    form = CountryLevelOptimization()
    # How to pass choices to the form['country'] 
    return render(request,"Dummy.html",{"form":form})
```

How can i pass choices to the country in from the view Homepage ?

please help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a dynamic choice field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field)

Comment: @Sam i actually have followed the steps of **Creating a dynamic choice field** link showed by you. But, how do i get the request back. **wayout(request.POST)** does not work as we are passing only 1 argument. But our class is taking two arguments

Comment: Could you update your question with the latest code so that I can take a look at it? Thanks in advance!