# Django changes dropdown menu

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

The code starts below, specifically for models and views -

```
class userchoice(models.Model):
choice = []
choice2 = list(userdata.objects.all().values_list('key'))
for x in choice2:
    for t in x:
        choice.append((t,t.capitalize()))

Job_ID = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length=200, choices=choice, default='key')
Group_ID= models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choice, default='key')
Customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choice, default='key')
Planned_Duration = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choice, default='key')
Worker_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choice, default='key')
Job_note = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choice, default='key')
Customer_tp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choice, default='key')
```

from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('csvfileapp', '0008_userdata'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='userchoice',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('Job_ID', models.CharField(default='key', max_length=200)),
            ('Group_ID', models.CharField(default='key', max_length=200)),
            ('Customer_name', models.CharField(default='key', max_length=200)),
            ('Planned_Duration', models.CharField(default='key', max_length=200)),
            ('Worker_name', models.CharField(default='key', max_length=200)),
            ('Job_note', models.CharField(default='key', max_length=200)),
            ('Customer_tp_name', models.CharField(default='key', max_length=200)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far, it's not a good solution at all. because choices can change anytime (because it's fetching database result) so any change lead to new migration file which is not good. Do as follow:

- just remove that part, make it a simple `charField`
- in your forms.py initiate the field that you want to have choices with the database query results you want.

To sum up, handle this situation in views and forms, not database orm and migrations!

#### Update:

Here's a code sample of forms.py to use:

```
class waypointForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(waypointForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['waypoints'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=[(o.id, str(o)) for o in     Waypoint.objects.filter(user=user)]
```

here's the [stack link for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 
But what changes would you suggest I should do in forms and views? 
I've used CharField only for all..
Can you please provide some code lines for reference?
AND how do I link those changes to Model?

Comment: Updated the answer